# Setting date for mysql database table

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a table with a list of People and their birthdays. I've managed to create the Person table with varchar(255) set for the names and date for the DOB. When I execute

```
update Persons set Birthday=2001-09-19;
```

it successfully executes the command but does not update the table when I view it. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: You need single quotes around the date.

Comment: `2001-09-19` means `subtract 9 from 2001, then subtract 19`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the single quotation mark

```
update Persons set Birthday='2001-09-19';
```